# help translating automated call for registration

Tags: telephone

I would like to register to Amazon web services and the during the verification's phone call I need to type 4 digit on my phone.
But the registration always fails, the truth is that i dont understand well the end of the instructions from "displayed on your screen ..."

the recorded call is here:
https://goo.gl/0kx18z

Can somebody help me to explain what it means the end of the call ?

Thanks in advance.

Cs.

I can turn to the Amazon support but I think they too busy to give answer in short term.

Comment: The instructions say to enter the four digits using your phone's number keys or you can speak the four digits into the phone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because EL&U is not a transcription service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hello, this is an automated call from Amazon Web Services. Using the touchpad on your phone, please enter the 4-digit PIN number that was displayed on your screen. ***You may also say your PIN one digit at a time***."

This is the exact transcription of the recorded voice.

Now, you have to make sure that you have the 4-digit PIN number that is displayed on your screen and make sure that you enter the 4-digit number exactly.

Entering the number on the touchpad would be easier than speaking the four digits into the phone.

Comment: @CsabaProg My pleasure. Hope you solved your problem. :-)

Comment: I said the given 4 digit, and it was successful finally :) maybe a typing from my smartphone has some problem - i dont know why, because it should be easy to do it, but not ... So saying the digits solved the registration. Thanks again.